# gradient vs partial derivative tangent plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So far in my math class we have learned two ways of finding tangent planes, and I'm having trouble reconciling them.

Say we have a function $2x+2y+2z=0$ and we're trying to find the tangent planet at point $(a,b,c)$. 



**Method One: Using the gradient**

Our tangent plane formula ends up being $2(x-a) + 2(y-b) + 2(z-c) = 0$

**Method Two: Using partial derivatives**

Our tangent plane formula ends up being $2(x-a) +2(y-b) + c = z$

Clearly those two tangent planes aren't the same. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partial derivative method works, you just did something incorrect. The normal to the tangent is $\vec n=<1,0,z_x> \times <0,1,z_y>=<-z_x,-z_y,1>$.

To find $z_x$ we use implicit differentiation, holding $y$ constant.

$$2+2z_x=0 \implies z_x=-1$$

To find $z_y$ we use implicit differentiation, holding $x$ constant.

$$2+2z_y=0 \implies z_y=-1$$

Hence the normal to the plane at some point is:

$$\vec n=<1,1,1>$$

Hence the equation of the tangent plane is:

$$1(x-a)+1(y-b)+1(z-c)=0$$

Multiplying both sides of the equation by $2$ gives:

$$2(x-a)+2(y-b)+2(z-c)=0$$

Which is exactly what you got using the gradient.